# Index specific terms filter in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a multi-match search query that I have previously restricted search results based on the client_code terms filter. This worked fine.

I now need to further restrict the results as certain users should only be able to return results for limited part or product ids. The part/product ids will vary and will be determined via application logic.

What I am struggling with as displayed in the non-functioning example below is how to apply terms filters for ids from each index.

```
GET parts,products/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "client_code": [
              "abc"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
             "products.id": [
              123,456,789
            ]
          }  
        },
        {
          "terms": {
             "parts.id": [
              abc123,abc456,abc789
            ]
          }  
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "foo",
            "fields": [
              "_id",
              "name",
              "sku",
              "title",
              "barcode"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, I can apply a terms filter like this:

```
    {
      "terms": {
         "id": [
          123,456,abc789
        ]
      }  
    }
```

However, if IDs are the same across indexes, which will be the case when data comes from auto-incrementing DBs, I need a way to say 'give me product ids 1,2 & 3 and part ids 1,3 & 4' for example. I hope that makes sense?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I could give more specific answer in case you had given data type , but from what you have provided you should have a look at Nested Query.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html